# How to remove or change the ID if the ID is IDENTITY COLUMN?

Tags: java, sql, derby

I have a certain problem with a database.
I have a Derby DB, the COUPON_ID column is determined by the identifier, and it increasing by 1.

Table example:

```
CREATE TABLE Coupon
(
    COUPON_ID BIGINT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
    TITLE VARCHAR(30),
    START_DATE DATE,
    END_DATE DATE,
    AMOUNT INTEGER,
    TYPE VARCHAR(20),
    MESSAGE VARCHAR(300),
    PRICE DOUBLE,
    IMAGE VARCHAR(500),
    CONSTRAINT PRIME_COUPON_ID PRIMARY KEY(COUPON_ID)
);
```

Let's say, I entered new data or delete ..., and everything works OK. And here's a question when deleting.
And here's a question when I want to delete some data.
If I have a certain quantity of lines, will allow 1000 which and I intend to remove. Everything normally is removed and everything normally continues to work. But here a question, what should I do then with these empty lines?
If I want to insert into them some data, Derby refuses, because the id of the COUPON_ID column as the identified column and it increasing automatically.

And I would like that empty intervals of lines didn't collect.
 There is a decision to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

> But here a question, what should I do then with these empty lines? If I want to insert into them some data, Derby refuses, because the id of the COUPON_ID column as the identified column and it increasing automatically.

I'd be inclined to think that the reason you cannot reuse IDs is not so much that that your ID column is an identity column, but that it is marked `GENERATED ALWAYS`.  In any case, no "empty lines" result from deleting rows from the DB.  There are unused ID values afterward, but these effectively consume no space.

You should ignore the no-longer-used IDs.  The purpose of an autogenerated ID is *solely* to uniquely identify rows.  As such it matters only that the values serve that purpose.  No particular significance should be ascribed to the ID values, and certainly you should not care about gaps between them.

> And I would like that empty intervals of lines didn't collect. There is a decision to this problem?

If you were willing to change the column definition then you could probably give yourself the ability to re-use IDs, but you should not do so.  The gaps are not a problem to be concerned with unless you are performing so many deletions that you are running out of ID values.